# How do i unit test an exception that's being thrown by an "update user" endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, api, unit-testing, junit

I'm currently unit testing the endpoints of a **Spring Boot CRUD RESTful API** and i have the following *"Update user by its id"* endpoint that's composed of a **controller** and a **service** to implement its logic :

**Update controller** (it's mainly calling the logic of the service and defining some guidelines) :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
public class UpdateUserController {

    @Autowired
    UpdateUserService service;

    @PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser_whenPutUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.updateUser(id, user));
    }
}
```

**Update service** :

```
@Service
public class UpdateUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User updateUser(Long id, User user) {

        repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));

        user.setId(id);
        return repository.save(user);
    }
}
```

While everything seems to be working fine until now, i'd appreciate if someone could tell me what i could improve in the code above. Anyways, my controllers throw exception unit test is the problem i can't seem to solve :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UpdateUserController.class)
public class UpdateUserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UpdateUserService updateUserService;

    @Test
    public void updateUser_whenPutUser() throws Exception {

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test Name");
        user.setId(89L);

        given(updateUserService.updateUser(user.getId(), user)).willReturn(user);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mvc.perform(put("/users/" + user.getId().toString())
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("name", is(user.getName())));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_throw_exception_when_user_doesnt_exist() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(89L);
        user.setName("Test Name");

        Mockito.doThrow(new UserNotFoundException(user.getId())).when(updateUserService).updateUser(user.getId(), user);

        mvc.perform(put("/users/" + user.getId().toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

Although the *updateUser_whenPutUser* is passing, the exceptions unit test is resulting in :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<404> but was:<400>
Expected :404
Actual   :400
```

Which means it's getting a **400** response status instead of the expected **404** thrown by the exception.

Curiously, if i change my *@WebMvcTest(UpdateUserController.class)* to *@WebMvcTest(UpdateUserService.class)* it passes, but then my controllers main unit test fails. No idea why.

Would appreciate if someone could help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

First you can give your Test Annotation an expected type. Like this

```
@Test(expected = NotFoundException.class)
public void test(){
   ...
}
```

The reason why you get an **400** instead of an **404** is hard to say. I would suggest it has something to do with the `status()` methode. Maybe you can provide some more of the stacktrace? Or i think you need to debug your tests to find out where the exception happens.

Comment: It's weird because i'm using this same method in all my endpoints and it's only failing in this one.

Comment: debug your application and look in which line in breaks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution :

The reason it was returning a 400 response status error is because **no message body was being sent**.

This specific endpoint requires a message body written in JSON on the request :

```
@Test
public void should_throw_exception_when_user_doesnt_exist() throws Exception {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(89L);
    user.setName("Test Name");

    Mockito.doThrow(new UserNotFoundException(user.getId())).when(updateUserService).updateUser(user.getId(), user);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mvc.perform(put("/users/" + user.getId().toString())
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```